# To careen or not to careen?

Tags: word-usage

I'm stuck on a sentence I wrote in which I described a ball as having 'careened off a wall'. The more I look at it the more I wonder if it's poor usage. Various definitions suggest the word describes an almost out of control path veering  back and forth, but can it also be used to describe a sudden change of direction? I had thought that perhaps 'careered' might be a better choice, but I'm not sure on that either as the definitions suggest it's a speedy and uncontrolled passage in a specific direction. If all else fails I'll just fall back on 'deflected'!

Comment: Is this action an intended action or is the ball’s trajectory unplanned/undesired?

Comment: Maybe you’d like ***caromed***.

Comment: Without the sentence you wrote, we are all guessing...

Comment: "Careened off the wall" is reasonably idiomatic, though prior to about 1960 only "caromed" was used: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=careened+off+the+wall%2Ccaromed+off+the+wall&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccareened%20off%20the%20wall%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccaromed%20off%20the%20wall%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ccareened%20off%20the%20wall%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccaromed%20off%20the%20wall%3B%2Cc0

Comment: _Careen_ is something you do to a ship - https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/careen . It is used in the USA as a synonym for _carom_ or _career_.

Comment: In response to the fifth answer, the word has multiple uses, not just in relationship to ships, which I was well aware of.

Comment: As for the point about a carom, no, I had considered it briefly, but it doesn't work. A carom  is a billiard term that describes the cue ball striking two balls - there are multiple actions involved, not just one, so it doesn't work within the context I'm describing of a single deflection. If that still doesn't make sense I would suggest that perusing a clip on Youtube might help explain the physics behind it.

Comment: @timW - *carom* has [other definitions](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/carom).  M&W gives: *”to strike and rebound”* with example sentences of “The car caromed off a tree.” “A ball caromed off the wall”